# Trouble making a HTTPS request with Libcurl in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, openssl, libcurl

I have a Web Service hosted on Azure, that is secured under SSL via a Self Signed Certificate.

I am trying to connect to it with the following code

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://XXXXXXXX.cloudapp.net/XXXXXX.svc/getFilms");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "C:\\Users\\Jordan\\Desktop\\Jordan-8.pem");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\\Users\\Jordan\\Desktop\\Jordan-8.pem");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

I then receive the following error

```
* Connected to XXXXXXXXX.cloudapp.net
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
* CAfile: C:\Users\Jordan\Desktop\Jordan-8.pem
CApath: C:\Users\Jordan\Desktop\Jordan-8.pem
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
* Closing connection #0
* Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? I have researched online for quite some time but came up with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when this happens it's because the SSL certificates used by libcurl are outdated. I recommend switching to the [cert bundle here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) to see if you have better luck with it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Although it seems the problem lies with the fact my Self Signed Cert name does not match the URL of my Azure service.

Comment: @Jordan I would take a look at the script included with the cert pack. It should help you get a little closer to getting your self signed cert added.

Comment: yes the error was that the cert I originally created had a different CN than that of the service. 
I created a new cert with the correct name then extracted that to pem format and passed the path of that file to CAINFO within curl.